# Trying to redirect old URL is closest new url using 301 redirectmatch

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-301

Please, this is giving me a headache!

I redirected an old site (goo.gl/onQ3UM) to a new directory. 
I had all URLs from the old site redirect to the new homepage (which I now realise was a mistake as I got lots of 404's and soft 404's at the start of last week).

So I'm now trying to redirect each page individually to the closest matching page using a 301 redirect.

I changed the htaccess file to read:
    Redirect 301 /wp/new-homepage-feb162 /wp/home [(seems to work fine)]
    RedirectMatch 301 /mjs/weddings/(.*) /wp/home/grand-country-house-weddings-and-receptions-dorset/

When I perform a 'Fetch' in GSC goo.gl/onQ3UM/mjs/weddings/217-a-testimonial.html?7bffea3334ebaaaf8a005d78b5e86b8e= 300b60a21ae5159ab1e8cf12b7634b7b
It shows as redirecting to /wp/home/grand-country-house-weddings-and-receptions-dorset/?7bffea3334ebaaaf8a005d78b5e86b8e= 300b60a21ae5159ab1e8cf12b7634b7b

Which is almost right but I don't want the ?7bffea3334ebaaaf8a005d78b5e86b8e=300b60a21ae5159a b1e8cf12b7634b7b

How do I get rid of it??!!!

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written this is very confusing... but from my understanding is you're trying to make your URL look 'prettier' after it has been re-directed?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#To go from URL /example/example1/example2/example3
#To go to URL /example3
RewriteRule ^/example/example1/example2(/.+)$ /$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

So the above would turn:

```
www.example.com/example/example1/example2/example3
```

Into:

```
www.example.com/example3
```